# Component Presentation JSON data directly dumped on page

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-1.7

The DXA Component Presentation JSON data is being directly dumped to the rendered page occasionally.

We are using SDL Web 8.5 and DXA 1.7.

Any clue how that is happening?

Comment: check the history of the cp and page items to see what?

Comment: JSON data on page, that is not what you want to see...

Comment: It sounds like the views are not executing on the data returned.

Comment: not happening all the time so hard to discover, there is an SDL ticket, but didn't resolve the issue. https://gateway.sdl.com/apex/communityknowledge?articleName=000007277

Comment: Does it happen randomly on different pages and different component presentations or is this case unique to a single page and CP? If it is the former, it looks like there could be a potential thread lock issue with the DXA code base. Let us know!